# Is there a built-in way to fetch a single ActiveRecord attribute from the database (ignoring the in-memory value)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

Big caveat: we're using Rails 2 at my company. So I'm looking for an answer (if one exists) from ActiveRecord 2.

Is there a method already included in ActiveRecord to fetch the most up-to-date value of an attribute from the database, without calling `reload` or overwriting the current in-memory value?

For example:

```
p = Person.find(123)

# Now the in-memory value is "Joe", which would be overwritten
# if I called reload
p.nickname = "Joe"

# I want something like this to execute the equivalent of:
# SELECT 'nickname' FROM persons WHERE id = 123;
nickname_from_db = p.get_current_value(:nickname)
```

I realize what I'm asking would be very simple to implement myself; I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's already an ActiveRecord method that does what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `select` option.

`Person.find(123, :select => "nickname")`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this... so there's no more "direct" method, then? (I guess I'm just clarifying that there isn't, e.g., an instance method that wraps this.)

Comment: Person.find(p, :select => :nickname)

Comment: No. `nickname` is just a value and Rails doesn't know where it comes from. So you have to ask the *thing* where it came from for getting the current value: `Person`.

Comment: @BenjaminM: I didn't mean an instance method on `String`, but rather on `Person`. I.e., if I had a `Person` object, `p`, I thought maybe there'd be a method like `p.fetch_latest("nickname")` and that method would internally call `Person.find(p.id, :select => "nickname")`. Anyway, I'm guessing there isn't any such method; so I'll just do as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dirty attributes to get the previous value of the attribute

```
>> p = Product.first
>> p.name # foo
>> p.name = 'bar'
>> p.changes['name'] # ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: This is nice, but I'd like to get whatever the value currently is in the database *now*, not what it was when I first fetched the record. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't really understand. If you need to know the value as it is right now in the database, simply do another database query using acitve record?!

Comment: @BenjaminM: Yes of course; I was only asking this question because, as we all know, there are lots of handy convenience methods in ActiveRecord and Rails in general; so rather than write my own little helper function to do this (as in Kaeros's answer) I was just checking whether it already existed first.